# What is the functionality of SCHED_SOFTIRQ in linux?

Tags: scheduling, interrupt

Who raises this softirq? Is it raised on every time tick( based on timer interrupt?)

Does this make the kernel to shedule a runnable process? If yes, how does the handlers  of lower priority softirqs (HR_TIMER,RCU_SOFTIRQ) run since the execution is now process context(after a schedule ())?

Comment: I think the author of the question asked a similar question on the mailing list of kernelnewbies. I also had been searching for the same answer and came across the mail threads. Here is a link to the specific thread: https://lists.kernelnewbies.org/pipermail/kernelnewbies/2015-January/013354.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to kernel documentations:

> **Software Interrupt Context: Softirqs and Tasklets** 
>    Whenever a system call is about to return to userspace, or a hardware
>   interrupt handler exits, any 'software interrupts' which are marked
>   pending (usually by hardware interrupts) are run (kernel/softirq.c).
>
> Much of the real interrupt handling work is done here. Early in the
>   transition to SMP, there were only 'bottom halves' (BHs), which didn't
>   take advantage of multiple CPUs. Shortly after we switched from
>   wind-up computers made of match-sticks and snot, we abandoned this
>   limitation and switched to 'softirqs'.
>
> include/linux/interrupt.h lists the different softirqs. A very
>   important softirq is the timer softirq (include/linux/timer.h): you
>   can register to have it call functions for you in a given length of
>   time.
>
> Softirqs are often a pain to deal with, since the same softirq will
>   run simultaneously on more than one CPU. For this reason, tasklets
>   (include/linux/interrupt.h) are more often used: they are
>   dynamically-registrable (meaning you can have as many as you want),
>   and they also guarantee that any tasklet will only run on one CPU at
>   any time, although different tasklets can run simultaneously.
>  **Caution**
>
> The name 'tasklet' is misleading: they have nothing to do with
>   'tasks', and probably more to do with some bad vodka Alexey Kuznetsov
>   had at the time.
>
> You can tell you are in a softirq (or tasklet) using the in_softirq()
>   macro (include/linux/interrupt.h).
>  **Caution**
>
> Beware that this will return a false positive if a bh lock (see below)
>   is held.

Comment: Also visit the http://lwn.net/Articles/520076/

Comment: Could you please be more specific to my question regarding sched_softirq?

Comment: I have a good suggesstion: download source of kernel and read include/linux/interrupt.h  and its implementation.